# DAO method retrieve single entry

Tags: java, database, hibernate, dao

How can I write DAO method which will return as a result only first entry from the database. For instance lets say I'm looking at Users table and I want to retrieve only the first entry, I'd declare method like:

```
public User getFirstUser(){
    //method logic
}
```

**EDIT:**

User has primary key **id** if that matters at all.

I apologize if this question is too simple/stupid/whatever I'm beginner with Java so I'm trying new things. thank you

**My attempt :**

```
   public User getFirstUser(){
            try { 
                final String getQuery = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Id = (SELECT MIN(Id) FROM Users)"; 
                final Query query = getSession().createQuery(getQuery); 
                final int rowCount = query.executeUpdate(); // check that the rowCount is 1 
                log.debug("get successful"); 
//             return what??
            } catch (RuntimeException re) { 
                log.error("get not successful", re); 
                throw re; 
            } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

- use:

  ```
  Query query = session.createQuery("from User");
  query.setMaxResults(1);
  User result = (User) query.uniqueResult();
  ```
- use `User user = session.get(User.class, id);` if you know the ID upfront.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to downvote this answer: 1. `uniqueResult()`  will throw an exception if the query returns more than one result (which is very likely the case of `from User`) 2. Don't retrieve all Users if want only one of them (what if there are 10⁶ users in the table?) 3. Don't use `LIMIT` which is not portable, use `setMaxResults()` and let Hibernate do its job.

Comment: thanks, updated. (6-hour meetings do bad things to people :) )

Answer (score 2):

Get all users ordered by id and limit the results to 1 (but don't use `LIMIT`, use `setMaxResults()` to remain portable):

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from User u order by u.id");
q.setMaxResults(1);
User u = (User) q.uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Id = (SELECT MIN(Id) FROM Users)`

:)

Answer (score 0):

Don't remember exactly but i think there is a method getSingleResult in JPA and also in Hibernate so...

But this method perhaps throw exception when multiple results are returned... can't remember...

Actually there is also getResultList returning a List of entities, and you could do list.get(0) no?

Or create a query with LIMIT 1?

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL Server we do it like,

First user, min ID,

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Users ORDER BY Id
```

Latest user, max ID,

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Users ORDER BY Id DESC
```

thanks.

Comment: yup.. this'll work in sybase as well. in oracle it'd be Select * from Users where rownum = 1